# after checkbox checked, redirection to a textbox

Tags: html, css, redirect, checkbox

Is it possible that when I check a checkbox it redirects me directly to a textbox ?
Like if I did a TAB when I check it.

And if possible only with HTML and CSS

Comment: Do you mean setting focus on a textbox when a checkbox is clicked?

Comment: your tried code pls? with a fiddle

Comment: Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Comment: This can't be done with HTML or CSS, but it *can* be done with JavaScript, with or without one of its libraries.

Comment: ok thanks, I think I really need to learn Java Script now -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with just HTML & CSS

but here is a solution using javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var checkbox = document.getElementById("agree"),
      textbox = document.getElementById("textbox");

  checkbox.onclick = function() {
    if(this.checked) {
      textbox.focus();
    }
  };
};
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/qeheqare/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the minimal implementation would be:

```
<form name="f1">
    <input id="in1" name="in1" type="checkbox" onClick="if(this.checked) document.f1.in2.focus()" /> Check option <br/>
    <input id="in2" name="in2" type="text" />
</form>
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Y2t2/)

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way is to use TabIndex attribut in the input element

```
<input type="checkbox" Tabindex="1"> </input>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" Tabindex="2"> </input>
```

I hope this might help you